# на C# написать сервер (win/lin) + клиенты (win/lin) ...глупая идея?

Tags: c#, xamarin, кроссплатформенность

Нахожусь в начале пути освоения C#. Пока весьма мутно представляю его возможности в полной мере. Знаю, что он пытается стать кросплатформенным (Xamarin) ... возник такой вот вопрос:

Можно ли написать кроссплатформ клиент-серверное приложение исключительно на C# ?
серверная чать под винду и линукс....запускается в виде сервиса и ждет подключений от клиентов.
и клиентская часть - также под вин/линукс...клиенты конектятся к серверу и отсылают/получают данные.

как пример - рендер менеджер или простой мессенджер со своим сервером...

Comment: .net core или asp.net core в помощь

Comment: Как то рано вы начали задумываться о кроссплатформенности, если даже возможностей языка не знаете. В вашем вопросе можно сделать одну маленькую поправку "пытается стать кросплатформенным (**.Net Core**)" и все, вот ответ на ваш вопрос. Ну а вообще, ваш вопрос как по мне довольно странный, что от нас вы ожидаете услышать, "Да"?

Comment: сейчас я использую C# для написания кода под Unity. Хотелось бы расширить немного свои познания дальше Unity и соответсвенно и сложился такой вопрос.

Comment: Понимаете-ли в чем дело... Если вы задаете подобный вопрос, то как по мне вы мало чего знаете про язык, если же вы про него мало знаете, то писать приложения под разные платформы для вас еще очень рано. Поймите как все работает, узнайте базу, углубитесь в это все получше и тогда уже думайте о кроссплатформенности, иначе сейчас вы попросту будете распылять свои силы на все подряд. Я вам советую найти для себя интересный проект, который вы в свободное время будете писать и усовершенствовать, не смотрите на окружающих, пишите для себя, ну или open source, со временем вы заметно поднимите навык.

Comment: `Можно ли написать кроссплатформ клиент-серверное приложение исключительно на C# ?` Вы не корректно задаете вопрос. C# - это **язык** программирования. А то на какой ОС он сможет запускаться зависит от среды выполнения. Например .Net Framework - исключительно под Windows, а вот .Net Core - уже кроссплатформенный, который если не использовать некоторые особенности ОС может выполняться как на Windows, так и на Linux.

Comment: Спасибо всем. Немного поясню.Я хотел спросить возможно ли такое в принципе и имеет ли смысл.Я не собираюсь заниматься этим сейчас. Просто интересны перспективы, допустим "программиста на C#". Если бы я все знал, то сам бы ответил на свой вопрос. Конечено, то что я описал теоретически можно посроить на каком угодно языке, на какой угодно платформе - ситуации будут отличапться набором костылей! так вот писать подобное на шарпе-это те же костыли или вполне приемлемо и не будут другие крутить пальцем у виска мол "возьми плюсы и немного питона и сделай то что хочеш, а на шарпе такое делать - изврат

Comment: @robox В коммерческом проекте обычно выбирается инструмент (язык программирования) под потребности. А в некоммерческом - как душе угодно. Например, у меня много моих сервисов крутится на .Net Core под линуксом. Почему не python/nodejs/ещечегонить? А потому что мне так нравится, лично мне привычней на C#.

Comment: вот собственно да ! в этом и был вопрос. Если я правильно понял, обладая навыками кодинга на шарпе можно в принципе развернуть  клиент-серверную систему и написать какой угодно функционал. и .NET Core будет вполне достаточно для этого